# How to Remove Zend Studio Components from Existing Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse PDT Indigo installed. I downloaded it form zend's  site. From the first day it was prompting me to try the original product Zend Studio. But eclipse PDT was actually serving purpose as it did for many years. But one day I installed it. Just clicked a tempting button.

Now I dont want to use it. Still 15 days remaining. But How do I remove it? From the software center I try to uninstall it. But how do I do it?

#### What have I tried?

I opened the Help menu. There was "install new software". Nothing like "uninstall". I though in the "install new software" dialog there might be a way to deselect them. But no. There is no way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Under Indigo/3.7 the "Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software tab > Uninstall..." option works. For some.

*Source:* [FAQ How do I remove a plug-in?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F)

Please let me know if that solved your issue.

Comment: :-S I found it in *About Zend Studio* Help menu item. I selected all of Zend Studio Items and removed them. It told me that it requires a restart. After shutting down its not starting. I tried running from command line, Some Java exception were thrown.

Comment: urgs. contact zend, write them you have encountered a problem with their software. Tell them what you did and which exceptions are thrown. A good IDE vendor normally reacts to support request within 2-12 hours with a clear path to a solution. Otherwise consider to re-install Indigo + PDT. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise).  I re-install it for now.

Comment: That is maybe faster, yes ;) Good luck!

Comment: Dude you saved my day :). I could give you 100 ups if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I went to zend-eclipse-php/plugins directory and removed all com.zend stuff from there (files and directories). Don't know what was gone but Eclipse stopped bugging about the license. And don't know what's that org.zend stuff - at least the name implies it's not commercial.

That's pretty much the standard way of getting rid of unnecessary Eclipse plugins.